# Android: spacing around bigContentView in notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, remoteview

I'm placing custom content in my notification using 'bigContentView', setting it to the same `remoteViews` as that which I've already established for a widget on the homescreen.  The problem I'm having is that the height of the notification content seems to remain constant, and does not shrink to fit the content.

As an example, when I resize the widget, the new widget content is placed in the notification, but it is always the same height (with the gaps filled in white):

[image]

The relevant code is as follows:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(placeName)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(drawableId)
        .setOngoing(false)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
        .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .build();
notification.bigContentView = remoteViews;
notificationManager.notify(0, appWidgetId, notification);
```

And the remoteViews is based on the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:id="@+id/widget" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_port"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(There is some other content in the layout, but the above is the basic layout, and I don't think the rest will have a material effect... certainly the layout works fine as an `AppWidget` context.)

EDIT: the imageview is updated with:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(imageViewId, uri);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong to prevent the notification actually fitting the `remoteViews` content?

Comment: And could you show where and how do you set the `ImageVIew` image?

Comment: @rom4ek I've update the question with this information

Comment: Have you tried `RelativeLayout` and `ImageView` with `wrap_content` height?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Android reserved the height of notification! Although Height of Big Notification Style also Reserved! You Have to create your notification according to these size.

Also the aspect ration of your image inside notification according to android native notification thing. Good Luck :)

Comment: What is your source for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"` in your `RelativeLayout` is causing the problem.

Try it after removing this line.

and one other thing that can cause this issue is your `ImageView` if above doesn't work for you you can try the following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/widget" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_port"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, please check the Width of your RemoteView! May be the Width and height are not able to set respectively. I've taken image of size 1920x1080 so I got the same output like yours. So please confirm it first. I've used your code and it works finely with proper sized image.

Please check this link: [Expandable Notifications for Android](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a "proper sized image"?  One with a very particular size, or aspect ratio, to match that of the notification, so that there is no gap?  You can't get the notification area to shrink to fit the image?  Perhaps one of the answers is right, that the height of the notification is reserved by Android?  I just can't see any reference to that being the case.

Comment: I mean to say that the aspect ration does matter for the notification content view either normal or extended. Please be maintained about aspect ratio please refer this [link](https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-content).